# How to get the field value in comptime in zig

Tags: zig

I want to make a deserializer in Zig. Now I could iterate the field information in comptime. But I want to get the field default value in struct. Is there a way to get them? For example, I want to get the `zzzz`'s value `100` in `getIntOrDefault`.

```
const std = @import("std");
const meta = std.meta;
const trait = meta.trait;
const assert = std.debug.assert;

pub fn deserializeInto(ptr: anytype) !void {
    const T = @TypeOf(ptr);
    comptime assert(trait.is(.Pointer)(T));

    const C = comptime meta.Child(T);

    ptr.* = switch (C) {
        []const u8 => "test string",
        else => switch (@typeInfo(C)) {
            .Struct => try deserializeStruct(C),
            .Int => try getIntOrDefault(C),
            else => @compileError("Unsupported deserialization type " ++ @typeName(C) ++ "\n"),
        },
    };
}

pub fn getIntOrDefault(comptime T: type) !T {
    return 2;
}

pub fn deserializeStruct(comptime T: type) !T {
    var value: T = undefined;
    inline for (meta.fields(T)) |struct_field| {
        try deserializeInto(&@field(value, struct_field.name));
    }
    return value;
}

pub fn main() !void {
    const T = struct {
        wwww: []const u8,
        zzzz: u32 = 100,
    };

    var v: T = undefined;

    try deserializeInto(&v);
    std.debug.print("zzzz value is {d}\n", .{v.zzzz});
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Zig 0.11+

The default value is [available](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/0.11.0/lib/std/builtin.zig#L316) as `@typeInfo(T).Struct.fields[...].default_value`. But it is stored as a pointer to `anyopaque`, you won't be able to dereference it, unless you cast it with [`@ptrCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/#ptrCast) like that:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    const TestStruct = struct {
        foo: u32 = 123,
    };
    std.log.info("{}", .{ TestStruct{} });

    const foo_field = @typeInfo(TestStruct).Struct.fields[0];
    std.log.info("field name: {s}", .{ foo_field.name });

    if (foo_field.default_value) |dvalue| {
        const dvalue_aligned: *const align(foo_field.alignment) anyopaque = @alignCast(dvalue);
        const value = @as(*const foo_field.type, @ptrCast(dvalue_aligned)).*;
        std.log.info("default value: {}", .{ value });
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
$ zig build run
info: main.main.TestStruct{ .foo = 123 }
info: field name: foo
info: default value: 123
```

#### Zig 0.10

The [`@ptrCast`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.10.1/#ptrCast) usage used to look like this:

```
const dvalue_aligned = @alignCast(foo_field.alignment, dvalue);
const value = @ptrCast(*const foo_field.type, dvalue_aligned).*;
std.log.info("default value: {}", .{ value });
```

Comment: Is manual construction of a `Pointer` type really the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: I noticed that you used `.size` and `.alignment` in the code. If I don't know the type of foo, how can get those infomation and construct a Pointer type?

Comment: @Hanaasagi `.size` and `.alignment` and not related to the type of `foo`.
Anyway, I've done some experiments and found a simpler way to do this. See updated answer.